# Solspace Calendar filter by day

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Maybe I'm just completely missing something, but I've looked through the docs a few times and haven't been able to find an answer. I'm working on building a way for people to go through events and filter them by day and time. Is there a way in Calendar to filter events by day? I haven't been able to find anything about it.

For example, I'd really like to be able to simply put something along the lines of:

`{exp:calendar:cal day="thur"}`

to only display events that occur on Thursdays. But so far, I haven't been able to find anything along those lines and I'd rather stay away from doing a somewhat complicated if statement. Especially with the number of filters I'm creating. I'm also using some query strings to filter, but I assume that wouldn't be an issue if I can just figure out how to filter events by day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a simple parameter for this. You must provide a time window for `{exp:calendar:cal}`, then filter for your day using a conditional. Here's a simple example for getting all events on Thursday for the current month:

```
{exp:calendar:cal
   date_range_start="year-month-01"
   date_range_end="year-month-last"
   pad_short_weeks="n"}
   {events}
      {if '{event_start_date format="%l"}' == "Thursday"}
         // Your event data
      {/if}
   {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Of course, in a different scenario, if you have a specific date and want to "zoom in" on that date (eg. Jan 30th, which was a Thursday), you can also set `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` on the same date to display only events on that day:

```
{exp:calendar:cal
   date_range_start="2014-01-30"
   date_range_end="2014-01-30"
   pad_short_weeks="n"}
   {events}
      // Your event data
   {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

You can use also URI segments to determine what is used in the `date_range_start=""` and `date_range_end=""` parameters.

The `pad_short_weeks="n"` parameter is also important to avoid including all days from a full week row.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use that method. Is that something the could possibly be included in a future version? Or is that something that's not really in the picture?

Comment: The functionality is already there, so it's unlikely a feature doing the same would be added anytime in the near/medium future.